# Traefik ingress route is not accessible

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress, ingress-controller

I have setup the default traefik dashboard example although this is not being exposed. Using kubectl port-forward works. The only thing that comes to mind is that I am using flannel as CNI and my previous k8s cluster instance I was using calico. It is weird though as I have other services exposed  from the cluster outside of traefik that are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper answer but it seems that Flannel CNI was causing reachability issues. It was either a misconfiguration from my end or some fine tuning the tool was needed. I just replaced it with Calico and ingresses work fine!